# How do I remove subway routes?

Tags: cities-skylines

I'm trying to reorganize my subway system, and in the process, I need to remove some currently active loops.  How do I do that?

I know I can click on one to select it, but it seems I can only add stations to the route, not remove them.  There must be something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by right-clicking at the station.  If you have multiple routes at a station, you may not notice that the route is being removed, but keep on right-clicking, and eventually you get them all.  Additionally, you can click and drag a route to a new station, which also applies to bus an rail routes.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way that didn't involve clobbering your subway route system.

Comment: I think part of my problem was that I set up my system as full loops instead of lines.

Answer (score 9):

If you'd like to delete an entire transit line, you can do this by clicking on the Transit overlay from the info panel in the top left corner, which allows you to click on transit lines to modify their name or color. There is also a "Delete line" button.

I found this somewhat confusing as there doesn't seem to be a way to access this from the Transit menu which you use to place lines and buildings, or add/delete/move stops.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Transit info panel, and select the metro/subway tab.  Then scroll through the list of subway lines.  When your pointer is over top of a line, it will glow on the (now white) city map (even if it was hidden - we're about to get to "hidden").

Feel free to also change the color of the line so it is distinctive and you know you're not handling another line by mistake.

Once you know which line it is, note the "eye" icon in the leftmost column of the chart. That will make the line visible or invisible. The eye at the top will show or hide ALL the lines.

So hide all the lines, then show only the line you wish to edit/delete.

Having done so, now go to the bottom-edge menu. Select transit and the tab for subway (or whichever) and the route creation tool.  Now you are seeing only the line you wish to change, because you hid the others.

Float over the dot at a station.  You can drag the line to add stops, drag a node to move stops, or right-click the node to delete the stop.